# Java Self-Programmed Singly-Linked-List in Linked-List

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

At least for me, I have a tricky exercise to do for university. The task is to program a singly-linked-list with all kind of methods. So far so easy, but the challenge is to store these singly-linked-lists afterwards in a Linked-List. In the following you see my implementation of my singly-linked-list which actually runs smoothly:

```
public class Liste {

ListenElement first;
ListenElement last;
ListenElement current;
int count;

public Liste() {
    first = null;
    last = null;
    current = null;
    count = 0;
}

// Methods...
```

The single-linked list consists of list elements implemented in the following:

```
public class ListenElement {

String content;
ListenElement next;

public ListenElement(String content, ListenElement next)
{
    this.content = content;
    this.next = next;
}

//Methods...
```

Here is my problem:

```
LinkedList<Liste> zeilen = new LinkedList<>();
Liste zeile1 = new Liste();
Liste zeile2 = new Liste();

zeile1.addBehind("Hello");
zeile1.addBehind("World");
zeile2.addBehind("Hello");
zeile2.addBehind("World");

zeilen.add(zeile1);
zeilen.add(zeile2);

System.out.print(zeilen.get(1));
//Printed: Listen.Liste@4aa298b73 instead of Hello World.
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your code never even calls `zeilen.add()`.  How can we debug this for you?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim! For what ever reason I lost this part by creating the question. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> System.out.print(zeilen.get(1));
> ```
>
> //Printed: Listen.Liste@4aa298b73 instead of Hello World.

That's the output of the default `Object#toString`. If you want different output from your `Liste` class, you need to override `toString` to provide that different output.

For example: If you wanted `Liste#toString` to return a comma-delimited list of the `toString`s of its contents:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(10 * this.count); // Complete guess
    ListenElement el = this.first;
    while (el != null) {
        sb.append(el.content.toString());
        el = el.next;
        if (el != null) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

(I'm making assumptions there about how your list class works, based on the code you showed...)